# Rails same route (POST /users) for different controller actions [Devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails api application where I am using Devise gem for user management. I created a user model off the devise gem. After that, I noticed that I have two same routes listed in the `rake routes`command. I want `POST (/users)` to call `api/v1/users#create` action first and then call `devise/registrations#create`.

```
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)        devise/registrations#create
api_users POST           /users(.:format)        api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json}
```

When I test `POST (/users)` using users_controller_spec file, `api/v1/users#create` action is called. However, when I do a `POST (/users)` using POSTMAN, the logs indicates that `devise/registrations#create`action is called instead.

How do I correct this so that the `POST (/users)` I do using POSTMAN or curl calls `api/v1/users#create` first to create the user model and then calls `devise/registrations#create` to register the user?

I am not 100% sure how devise works so any help here would be helpful.

This is my `config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      # We are going to list our resources here
      resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you please post your **`config/routes.rb`** file?

Comment: Your rails version please, also just want to know what type of request you are hitting to this methods, eg json, html etc, please post your routes file also @millin

Comment: I am doing json request, because I can creating an API @ManojMenon

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I have update the question and included my `config/routes.rb`

Comment: You have added users resources twice. devise_for :users and resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]

Answer (score 1):

So, the thing with Rails Routes is, when you make a request, routes are checked as they are defined in the `routes.rb` from top to bottom.

Now, when you make a request via `POSTMAN`, the `/users` path matches with a path generated via `devise_for`, as it is the first line in the file.

Now, when you are writing tests for the controller, you are not really accessing `/users`, you are just telling the `api/v1/users_controller` to invoke the `create` method, which is bound to hit the `api/v1/users#create`

Now, a way you can resolve this conflict is by changing what `devise` names its routes. If you do something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: 'customer'
  # Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      # We are going to list our resources here
      resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

This is what the devise routes will be:

```
      new_user_session GET    /customer/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /customer/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /customer/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /customer/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /customer/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /customer/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
...
```